# Alternate way for string replace and array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, string

Is there any way to replace titles faster then str_replace function? I've got a file that is 2000 lines of array changes. That hurts my webpage.

Comment: One time?  Every time your page loads?  More specifics would be helpful.

Comment: @manos I'm replacing bad words in table listing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short... no. It doesn't get much faster than str_replace when it comes to replacing text. I don't know where this data is coming from, but I'd suggest changing your application to do this only once and then store the result somewhere. On subsequent request just return the transformed data.

It's either that or upgrading the machine this runs on.

Answer (score 0):

For that number of replacements, you will see considerable performance loss if you are calling `str_replace` for each replacement. Calling it once with an array of the before and after is much faster.